# vs code remote container can't find docker command, how can I configure it?

Tags: makefile, dockerfile, containers, remote-debugging, vscode-extensions

i have this set up with Ubuntu 16.04 with that Dockerfile and did everything as instructed:
https://github.com/KleinYuan/RGGNet

I can't debug the container through the terminal, so I want to rebuild my container in VS Code to debug it.

I tried the VS Code remote container extension and opened that folder and it built the image from the Dockerfile and did `make build` as instructed to build the container.

But it can't build it because `make` calls `docker` but can't find it. I don't know why it's not finding it; it works from the command line.

I compared it with my container locally and it has different Paths than my local one which is Bash.

So how can I do it right to build/make run this image from within VS Code?
Maybe there is a better way to debug the container? Can VS Code debug without the remote extension?

This image shows the image inspection of the VS Code container image on the left; on the right is the local as in github description.

[image: left is the image inspection of the vscode container image,right the local as in github description]

When I run `make` I get this:

```
root@48ced9c57f05:/workspaces/RGGNet-master# make run
docker run -it \
        --gpus all \
        --net=host \
        --privileged=true \
        --ipc=host \
        --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro" \
        --env="DISPLAY" \
        --env="QT X11 NO MITSHM=1" \
        --hostname="inside-DOCKER" \
        --name="rggnet-experiment" \
        -v /workspaces/RGGNet-master:/root/rggnet \
        -v /home/work/Documents/projektarbeit/RGGNet-master/training data serialization/kitti:/root/kitti \
        rggnet-docker bash
/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 127
```

Comment: and i'm new in coding with docker,linux,tensorflow and makefiles.

Comment: The command is executed by `/bin/sh` and it prints its name in front of any error message, like any good tool should. The error message simply means `docker` is not in your `PATH`. Did you forget to install it?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: no i have docker installed, but just locally , so in my normal terminal docker is working. but in visualstudio code i can't execute the makefile because docker is not found.

so why did visualstudio code change my local path, or where does it settle it and what do i have to change.

oh but why don't post pictures? isn't it more clear then?

Comment: The previous comment contains a link to a fuller explanation of why pictures are problematic; please click it to learn more.

Comment: If you installed Docker normally it should be somewhere obvious like `/usr/bin/docker`. If you installed it in some weird place (as a snap maybe?) you might have to separately configure that in VS Code. This could also depend on how you installed VS Code, and how you run it. If you start it from a terminal where you have Docker in your `PATH`, VS Code should inherit that `PATH`.

Comment: yes,but thats actually my question i know that  docker is somewhere but i don't know how to configure it in the .json file in or somewhere in cv code

Comment: thx, ok i will put my code in when i reproduce it and have the time

Comment: I tried to clean up your post but there are some things which I could not understand. What does "which is Bash" mean here? Obviously, my manual OCR of your screen shot might contain transcription errors; please review.

Comment: Anyway, the error message looks like you are trying to run `docker` _inside your running Docker image_ where `docker` is probably not installed, and where you almost certainly don't want to run it anyway.